# Wicket FilterToolbar not nulling long value on backing model when invalid user input

Tags: java, datatable, wicket

We are using FilterToolbar for our DataTables in our wicket 1.5.5 app.

We have encountered a problem when the backing model property of a filtered toolbar is Long.class. Everything works properly if the user puts in valid input, say '123'. The problem occurres when the following steps happen:

1) user puts in valid input ("123"), and filters by submitting the form.
2) user puts in invalid input ("abc") and filters by submitting the form.

When the user submits the form in step 2, the backing models long field will still be set to 123, instead of null which would be the desired behaviour.

Could this be a bug in wicket or am I causing the problem somehow?

Thanks in advance!
Olle

Comment: This is default (and desired) behavoiur. The models do not get updated/changed if an conversion/validation error occours.

Comment: Adding to @bert's comment, if you'd like to have that kind of behavior, you should probably implement your own [`IConverter`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/) and use it in the component modelling the `Long` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way wicket handles models. They aren't changed if the new input isn't valid. You should be able to work around this by implementing an `onError` method in your form that writes null values to invalid fields. onError is called instead of `onSubmit` if the input contains invalid values.